# How should I insulate rim joist cavities behind backing blocks?

Tags: basement-insulation

I am finishing a basement with 2" EPS on the poured walls and then doing the rim joist and sill plate with the same 2" EPS.  My question is along 2 sides of the building there are 2x8 backing blocks that are acting as a ledger for a deck and porch. Thanks for the replies.I am using 2" EPS.  There  is 1 or in some cases 2 lag bolts coming through the backing which is why its there in the first place. There were plain fiberglass batts stuffed in there before. I don't think I will be able to get the 2" up behind it.
So the question is should I just leave the batt insulation in those sections or do something else?
Thanks[image]

Comment: I don't see how those blocks are an impediment. What's behind them? Why did you remove the fiberglass in the first place?

Comment: Why don't you think you'll be able to get the EPS foam board up there? Are you using 1" thick boards doubled up or a single 2" thick board?

Comment: Is the issue that there are screws coming through the space to hit the blocking? Perhaps some spray foam

Comment: Thanks for the replies.I am using 2" EPS.  Yes there is 1 or in some cases 2 lag bolts coming through the backing which is why its there in the first place.  Yes there were plain fiberglass batts stuffed in there before.

Comment: @JerryMorrison If you haven't already bought 2" foam it would be easier to install 1" foam; just get twice as much 1" foam instead and double it up. Also I would recommend XPS as well instead of EPS ...if you haven't already purchased it.

Comment: Do you have some pictures from further out?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few options:

1. leave the batt insulation
2. build out the framing to the sill, fill with batt, apply vapour barrier
3. build out the framing to cover the foundation as well, ceiling to floor, and apply batt + VB.
4. as you suggest, apply EPS, or better, XPS. Cut it in horizontal strips, leave a slot for the deck's ledger screws, and slide under. Apply technical tape at horizontal seams. If the gap is 12" high, this might work with 6" high strips.

For 4, you can additionally apply spray foam into the perimeter of the cavity and promptly insert the board thus "squishing" the foam and creating a tight seal.

Comment: Typically you spray foam after you insert the board. This way the board is pressed up against the surface of the structure and the sprayfoam helps lock it in place.

Comment: @TylerH yes, but if he can't get into the cavity, pre-spraying could be a viable alternative. But you have to be fast! Using extension tubing may help.